# Why My TextInput Fields Behave Differently On Different Screen. in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

I have Two To Radio Buttons. One Is Buyer and Other One Is seller. By clicking on buyer radio button buyer sign up page will open and by clicking on seller. seller sign up will open. Now I have Email And Password fields In both Sections. But In Buyer Screen. When I click on Email and password fields keyboard is automatically opening in Capital letter.But When I copy and paste Exact same code in seller side its working fine. any idea . thanks

Comment: please share the related code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

For your TextInput component, you may need to call the autoCapitalize prop, and set it to another value. By default, it is set to capitalize the first letter of the sentence. To fix this, set the prop autoCapitalize to none.

```
<TextInput autoCapitalize={'none'} />
```

Reference here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#autocapitalize

Comment: Thank You For Commenting. But I have provided autoCap = none also. Now I solved By Wrapping The Entire View in Another View. I do not know exact reason .why this works. May Its Bug In react native it self

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I would suggest you edit your OP and include your solution, so that others can find a solution too.